# Why I can't add controls to a c# form another class?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2013, drop-down-menu, controls

I have read and watched tutorials about adding controls while compiling, and I tried to implement them on my code, but isn't working. I check it on debug but it seems the **controls aren't even being added to the form**.

This is the class that I want to implement (Parents class has a List of Child class but them aren't necesary to show because in the debug I know them are recognized. Heights and DefaultWidth are static int on the DropDownMenu class)

```
[Serializable]
public class DropDownMenu
{
    public Button AddButton(string title, int height)
    {
        Button btn = new Button();
        btn.Text = title;
        btn.Size = new Size(DefaultWidth,height);
        return btn;
    }

    public FlowLayoutPanel AddDropDownLayoutPanel(int heightParent, int heightChilds, int numChilds)
    {
        FlowLayoutPanel flpDropDown = new FlowLayoutPanel
        {
            FlowDirection = FlowDirection.TopDown,
            MinimumSize = new Size(DefaultWidth, heightParent),
            MaximumSize = new Size(DefaultWidth, heightChilds*cantChilds)
        };
        return flpDropDown;
    }

    public FlowLayoutPanel AddDropDownButtons(int index, Point iniPos)
    {
        int numChilds = Parents[index].Childs.Count,
        minSizeP = numChilds*HeightChild,
        maxSizeP = minSizeP; //in this code I add more to this variable but right now is not really important

        FlowLayoutPanel flpDropDownP = AddDropDownLayoutPanel(HeightParent, HeightChild, numChilds);
        flpDropDownP.Location = iniPos;
        flpDropDownP.Tag = 1;
        flpDropDownP.Name = "flpParent" + index;

        Button p = AddButton(Parents[index].title, HeightParent);
        p.Name = String.Concat(isBtnParent, index);
        p.Location = new Point(0,0);
        p.Tag = 2;

        flpDropDownP.Controls.Add(p);
        flpDropDownP.MinimumSize = new Size(DefaultWidth, minSizeP);
        flpDropDownP.MaximumSize = new Size(DefaultWidth, maxSizeP);
        flpDropDownP.Size = flpDropDownP.MinimumSize;
        return flpDropDownP;
    }
}
```

And in the form I call it on the load event:

```
private void FrmContainer_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    DropDownMenu dropDownMenu = new DropDownMenu();
    List<Parent> parents = new List<Parent>();

    DropDownMenu.HeightParent = this.btnUsuario.Height;
    DropDownMenu.HeightChild = this.btnUsuario.Height - 2;

    try
    {
        List<Child> childs0 = new List<Child>
        {
            new Child{Id = "h0", Nombre = "Child 01"},
            new Child{Id = "h1", Nombre = "Child 02"}
        };
        parents.Add(new Parent{ Id = "p0", Nombre = "Parent 01", Childs = childs0 });
        parents.Add(new Parent{ Id = "p1", Nombre = "Parent 02", Childs= childs0 });

        dropDownMenu.Parents = parents;
        DropDownMenu.DefaultWidth = 128;

        Point iniBtnMenu = new Point(10, 20); //I have other numbers, but isn't really important here

        if (parents.Count != 0)
        {
            for (int index = 0; index < parents.Count; index++)
            {
                if (parents[index].Childs.Count != 0)
                {
                    this.Controls.Add(dropDownMenu.AddDropDownButtons(index, iniBtnMenu));
                }
                else
                {
                    Button n = dropDownMenu.AddButton(parents[index].Nombre, DropDownMenu.HeightParent);
                    n.Location = iniBtnMenu;
                    this.Controls.Add(n);
                }
                iniBtnMenu.X += DropDownMenu.DefaultWidth;
            }
        }
    }
catch (Exception ex)
{
}
```

}

I think they maybe are being created behind other elements on the form but then again in Visual studio, when I look at the controls added to the form, the buttons aren't there, so I suppose that's not the problem. I'm using Visual Studio 2013 (but I don't think it has any to do with it). At first I just create the button without size, location or name but when I checked on the Form1.Designer.cs all the controls have them, so I added them.

---

In summary, what I want is a drop down menu that depends on a list of objects (that later I can replace with some data from a DataBase) and it's childs (like menu and submenu). And I'm not using the default menu control from Visual Studio because I want to modify the design and I can't with that control.

Comment: Few things. 1. Ensure you are thinking of the correct Time. You Have Design time(when you write code) Build Time (When code is compiled) And RunTime (when your code is executed) 2. With that being said you want to Design time (write some code) that when executed at runtime will create a object dynamically. Lucky for you VS does it already and can be used as a great reference. as a demo. Create a new windows form project manually add a few objects then then look for the <formname>.Designer.cs file. this file will have all the controls.

Comment: Yes, after waching some tutorials about creating controls on runtime, I decided to check on that file (<formname>.Designer.cs) to know how the form was created, and there is when I decided to add Location, Size and Tag properties, but still isn't working...